# Contrast of the word "search" next to the expanded search box

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

On both Main and Meta, when you start typing into the Search box, and the box expands, the word "search:" next to the box is in white, which has a very low contrast with the light background.

Comment: Oh wow, didn't realize that word was still there!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build (after rev 2012.5.11.2538).

Comment: I see that it's fixed now; thanks!